# Java - Moving selected object from JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, java-2d

I am working on a given project which is similar to Paint program on Windows.
I have created buttons, which helped me to draw circles, rectangles, helped to clean the frame and etc. 
But i have faced the main problem. I want to select with mouse some region, which I would be able to move around the frame. Here is the code:

```
    package StreamProject;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class Paint extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    BufferedImage grid;
    Graphics2D gc;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int stroke, eraser = 0;
    private int xX1, yY1, xX2, yY2, choice;             // choice
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;  // set background  as white
    private int eraserW = 50;                   // the eraser width is set to 50
    private int eraserH = 50;                   // the eraser height is set to 50

Paint()
{

JFrame frame = new JFrame("PaintProgram");
frame.setSize(1200, 800);

frame.setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
frame.getContentPane().add(this);

JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);                     // this wll create a menu bar
JMenu opt = new JMenu("Options");
menuBar.add(opt);


JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem ("New");

    item = new JMenuItem ("Open new window");              opt.add(item);
    item.addActionListener(this);
    item = new JMenuItem("Save");         opt.add(item);
    item.addActionListener(this);

    item = new JMenuItem("Quit");   opt.add(item);

    item.addActionListener(this);

JButton pickUp = new JButton("Pick up image");
    pickUp.addActionListener(this);
JButton b1 = new JButton("Clear Drawing");
    b1.addActionListener(this);                 // button 1 passed to every ActionListener object that registered using addActionListener
JButton color = new JButton("Color");
    color.addActionListener(this);
JButton erase = new JButton("Erase");               // this button is set as Eraser
    erase.addActionListener(this);
JButton b2 = new JButton("Rect");             // this button is set as  Rect
    b2.addActionListener(this);                 // button 2 passed to every ActionListener object that registered using addActionListener
JButton b3 = new JButton("oval");             // this button is set as  Oval
    b3.addActionListener(this);                 // button 3 passed to every ActionListener object that registered using addActionListener
JButton b4 = new JButton("Line");               // this button is set as Line
    b4.addActionListener(this);                     // button 4 passed to every ActionListener object that registered using addActionListener
JRadioButton medium = new JRadioButton("Medium Line");      // there are radio button to choose Medium Line
    medium.addActionListener(this);
JRadioButton thick = new JRadioButton("Thick Line");        // there are radio button to choose Thick Line
    thick.addActionListener(this);

ButtonGroup lineOption = new ButtonGroup();
    lineOption.add(medium);                     // line for medium
    lineOption.add(thick);                      // line for thick
  this.add(pickUp);
  this.add(b1);
  this.add(color);
  this.add(erase);
  this.add(b2);
  this.add(b3);
  this.add(b4);
  this.add(medium);
  this.add(thick);
  addMouseListener(this);                     // receiving an event from the mouse
  frame.setVisible(true);                     // this frame is set visible to user
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       // the operation will automatically off when user clicked exit button

}

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   if (grid == null)
   {
    int w = this.getWidth();                        // width
    int h = this.getHeight();                       // height
     grid = (BufferedImage) (this.createImage(w, h));
     gc = grid.createGraphics();
      gc.setColor(Color.BLUE);
   }

   g2.drawImage(grid, null, 0, 0);
  check();
}

  public void draw()
  {
   Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
   int w = xX2 - xX1;
   if (w < 0)
   w = w * (-1);

    int h = yY2 - yY1;
     if (h < 0)
     h = h * (-1);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        check();
        gc.drawRect(xX1, yY1, w, h);
        repaint();
    }

    else if(choice == 2)
    {
        check();
        gc.drawOval(xX1, yY1, w, h);
        repaint();
    }

    else if(choice == 3)
    {
        if (stroke == 0)
        gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        if (stroke == 1)
            gc.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
            gc.drawLine(xX1, yY1, xX2, yY2);
            repaint();
    }

    else if(choice == 4)
    {
        repaint();
        Color temp = gc.getColor();
        gc.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        gc.setColor(temp);
        repaint();
    }


    else
    {
        if (eraser == 1)
            gc.clearRect(xX1, yY1, w, h);
    }
  }

        public void check()
         {
         if (xX1 > xX2)
           {
            int z = 0;
             z = xX1;
             xX1 = xX2;
             xX2 = z;
           }
         if (yY1 > yY2)
         {
          int z = 0;
          z = yY1;
          yY1 = yY2;
          yY2 = z;
         }
         }
//  public void saveMap() {
//      String sb = "TEST CONTENT";
//      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
//      chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/hikmet/Desktop"));
//      int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
//      if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
//          try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".png")) {
//              fw.write(sb.toString());
//          } catch (IOException e) {
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
//      }
//  }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        super.removeMouseMotionListener(this);

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Color"))
        {
            Color bgColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Choose Background Color", getBackground());
            if (bgColor != null)
                gc.setColor(bgColor);
  }

  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Quit")){
        System.exit(0);
  }

  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Save")){
//    saveMap();
  }

  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Open new window")){
     new Paint();
  }

  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Pick up image")){

  }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Rect")) { choice = 1; }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("oval")) { choice = 2; }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Line")) { choice = 3; }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Medium Line")) { stroke = 0; }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Thick Line")) { stroke = 1; }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Erase")) { eraser = 1; choice = 5; super.addMouseMotionListener(this); }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Clear Drawing")) { choice = 4;draw(); }

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { xX1 = e.getX(); yY1 = e.getY(); }

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { xX2 = e.getX(); yY2 = e.getY(); draw(); eraser = 0; }

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent re)
{
      Color c = gc.getColor();
      gc.setColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
      gc.drawRect(re.getX(), re.getY(), eraserW, eraserH);
      gc.setColor(c);
      repaint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
{
}



}
```

I want actually put all eventprocess in given snippet in code:

```
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Pick up image")){

  }
```

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: I want to implement movement of the object, which i will select with mouse

Comment: hi, You are assurely new with awt/swing, regarding the structure of your code. First, you will to remove all interfaces implemented and use dedicated classes you code is too long now and will not going shorter regarding what you want to do. so you need a little more organisation basically the behaviour that you search is not available with prebuild feature in swing or awt so you will have to do it your self ...

Comment: You r right, I am new with awt/swing, and thanks for advice)

Comment: are you using j8 or higher?

Comment: I am using intelliJ Idea